# Generate Code for three-address Statement

Tags: compiler-construction, assembly

i want to generate code for three-address statement assuming stack allocation where register SP points to the top of the stack. For example, x=y+1.

```
100:  LD SP, # 144
108:  ACTION1
128:  ADD SP,SP,#1
136:  BR *0(SP)
144:
```

Am i correct?

Comment: Looks like some distant relative of Z80